# Responsive Slider - How to not fade to background when fading between slide images

Tags: jquery, slider, transition, fade

I have implemented Responsive Slider on my test server:
http://test-orange.com/resp/

If you watch the slideshow you'll see that as each slide fades out and the next fades in, the background shows during the fade.

I do not want the background to show like this. I want each slide image to fade seemlessly to the next image.

Anyone know how I can modify the responsiveslides.js code to do this?
I think this is the part that needs to be edited:

```
      if (settings.auto === true) {
        setInterval(function () {
          $this.find(':first-child').fadeOut(fadetime, function () {
            $(this).css(hidden);
          }).next($slide).fadeIn(fadetime, function () {
            $(this).css(visible);
          }).end().appendTo($this);
        }, parseFloat(settings.speed));
```

Comment: switch sliders  might be best bet

Comment: Please provide link to the slider plugin's origin. Your demo link currently suffers from error 500..

Comment: The one that fades in and out with opacity and thus will not meet my needs is this one: http://responsive-slides.viljamis.com/... it's a perfectly fine slider, though! Just doesn't have this feature. The one I ended up using is this one: http://codecanyon.net/item/unoslider-responsive-touch-enabled-slider/657866

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a seamless fade, you won't get it with fade. When node fades, it looses opacity. With linear fade, on the half way, both nodes are half-opaque. One would assume 50% + 50% would sum to 100% and give a fully opaque image mixed fifty-fifty, but this is light, not oranges, it doesn't sum like so. With light it is like this:

```
opacity = layerA + (layerB * layerA)
```

What you'll end up with is a 75% opacity and that's what leaves the remaining 25% for the background to seep through from underneath in the middle of the fade. That's what cross-fade does. For extended reasoning see this nice [question and its answer(s)](https://superuser.com/questions/363296/why-do-two-50-opacity-layers-of-the-same-color-dont-make-the-solid-color-in-ph).

For smooth transition attaining 100% opacity full-time you need a different technique. You need to fade in the new slide over the previous, which does not fade at all. It stays at 100% and this way the background doesn't have a chance. Once the next slide is faded-in, you hide the previous one.

Generally, instead of this:

```
$previous.fadeOut(fadetime);
$next.fadeIn(fadetime);
```

you need this:

```
$next.fadeIn(fadetime, function(){
    $previous.hide();
});
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for explaining that so clearly. I actually already understood all that, but am currently not skilled enough at js or jquery to edit the core plugin code itself. I took a stab at rearranging these fades in the code, but understand why that wouldn't achieve my goal even if I did it correctly. UNO Slider on Code Canyon must use a different method for fade because it works great. slidejs aslo worked because it has an extra cross-fade ability, but it was jumpy on small devices. Thanks for your thoughtful answer!